# Использование переменной в регулярном выражении Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Салют!
Помогите пожалуйста решить казалось бы тривиальную, но за неимением опыта в 
программировании,абсолютно непосильную мне задачку :)

```
mt=re.findall(r'\'"variable"\s\'')
```

Вместо "variable" должна быть переменная,в которую будут подставятся разные строки,
а как это преподнести правильно не знаю.

Comment: в таких воспросах принято приводить небольшие примеры данных (строк в вашем случае) на входе и то что вы хотите получить на выходе... ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @минусовальщикам, не надо минусовать вопросы новых (неопытных) участников, лучше объяснить как они могут улучшить качество своих вопросов. PS кроме того поставив минус участнику с репутацией `1`, вы никакх не уменьшите репутацию данного участника, но подпортите свою карму - в вашем профиле счетчик отрицательных отзывов увеличиться на `1` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
reg_exp = r'\'' + variable + r'\s\''
mt=re.findall(reg_exp)
```

Comment: Говорит что: missing 1 required positional argument 'string'

Comment: Верно. Потому что findall требует два аргумента - что ищем, где ищем, а у вас один.

Comment: Да,действительно :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь !

Answer (score 6):

**Если коротко, то...**

Если в переменной содержатся шаблоны регулярного выражения:

```
reg_exp = r"'{}\s'".format(variable)
reg_exp = fr"'{variable}\s'"
```

Если текст переменной содержит буквальный текст:

```
reg_exp = r"'{}\s'".format(re.escape(variable))
reg_exp = fr"'{re.escape(variable)}\s'"
```

Регулярные выражения в Python задаются с помощью строковых литералов, поэтому проблема использования переменной в регулярном выражении в Python сводится к проблеме использования переменных в строковом литерале.

**Способы добавления переменной в строку**

Существует множество способов:

- Конкатенация строк ([предложена Эникейщиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/958035/182013)): `reg_exp = r"'" + variable + r"\s'"`
- Оператор форматирования строк `%s`: `reg_exp = r"'%s\s'" % variable`
- [Метод `str.format`](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html): `reg_exp = r"'{}\s'".format(variable)` или `reg_exp = r"'{x}\s'".format(x=variable)`
- Интерполяция строк (доступна с Python 3.6): `reg_exp = rf"'{variable}\s'"`

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/KjGzR1) (Python 3.7.3).

**Что выбрать?**

Интерполяция появилась относительно недавно, она доступна только в Python начиная с версии 3.5. Она удобна, так как переменные вставляются в строковой литерал как есть в фигурных скобках. Однако надо помнить, что двойные фигурные скобки задают буквальные фигурные скобки, `f"{{"`  = `{`, а `f"}}"` = `}`.

Метод `str.format` очень похож на интерполяцию. Задав один аргумент, его можно повторять сколько угодно раз с помощью `{x}`, где `x` — порядковый номер аргумента. `r"'{0}':\s+'{0}'".format(variable)` объявляет выражение `'abc':\s+'abc'`. Именные аргументы упрощают (иногда и сокращают) использование переменных в строке. `r"'{x}':\s+'{x}'".format(x=variable)` в результате даст то же выражение, что и в предыдущем примере. При задании нескольких аргументов, которые используются лишь один раз в строке, можно использовать `{}` без указания индекса: `another="def";print(r"'{}':\s+'{}'".format(variable,another))` даст выражение `'abc':\s+'def'`.

При конкатенации строк нет проблем с "экранированием" символов фигурных скобок (см. следующий абзац), но конструкция получается менее удобной для чтения и есть риск "забыть" какой-нибудь префикс (например, `r`).

**Интерполяция и фигурные скобки**

Будьте осторожны с фигурными скобками при интерполяции: двойные фигурные скобки задают буквальные символы `{` и `}`, что бывает очень важно при использовании интервальных квантификаторов:

```
# Интерполяция и фигурные скобки
print(f"{variable}")
# => abc
print(f"{{variable}}")
# => {variable}
print(f"{{{variable}}}")
# => {abc}
```

То же относится и к методу `str.format`:

```
print("{{}}".format(variable))
# => {}
```

**Специальные символы в переменной**

Если текст переменной может содержать специальные метасимволы регулярных выражений (например `(`, `)`, `[`, `+`, `*` и т.д.), рекомендуется использовать метод `re.escape`:

```
reg_exp = r"'{}\s'".format(re.escape(variable))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```